# @project.impressionist_count - wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, impressionist

I use rails 5

I want to count the number of views of the project

I installed `gem 'impressionist'`

Generate the impressions table migration

```
rails g impressionist
```

Run the migration

```
rake db:migrate
```

In view projects/show.html.erb

```
<%= @project.impressionist_count %>
```

**Displayed error on line <%= @project.impressionist_count %> wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)**  I am at a loss to identify the cause of the error.

**Logs:**

```
app/views/projects/show.html.erb:89:in `_app_views_projects_show_html_erb___149972252570834158_69970117978380'
  Rendering /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (8.9ms)
  Rendering /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (5.1ms)
  Rendering /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (121.7ms)
DEPRECATION WARNING: #original_exception is deprecated. Use #cause instead. (called from status_code_with_paginate at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/will_paginate-3.1.0/lib/will_paginate/railtie.rb:49)
```

**In rails console:**

```
pry(main)> project.impressionist_count
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:731:in `count'
```

**Model Project**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
 ..........................

  is_impressionable

.............................

end
```

**ProjectsController**

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :edit] 
  before_action :require_permission, only: [:edit]
  before_action :set_freelancer, only: [:show]
  before_action :set_response_current_user, only: :show, if:  :exist_response?
  after_action :verify_authorized, only: [:update]  

  impressionist :actions => [:show]

    def show
      @new_response = @project.responses.build
      impressionist(@project)
    end
...............................................
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **model** should be like:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
 ..........................
  include Impressionist::IsImpressionable
  is_impressionable

 .............................

end
```

In **controller**:

```
def show
  @new_response = @project.responses.build
  # impressionist(@project) //comment out this line
 end
```

Comment: i added include Impressionist::IsImpressionable. reloaded server same error

Comment: commenting out `impressionist(@project)`  from controller show method may solve the issue.